# django escapes widget when rendering form

Tags: django, escaping, widget

I created a custom widget, and a form that uses it.
Previously, I just had a simple template to show the form when I was debugging it:

```
<form>
    {{ run_form.as_p }}
</form>
```

Now I want to enclose each form field in a div, so I've changed the template to

```
{% for field in form %}
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
           {{ field.errors }}
           {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But now it seems that when my field is rendered, all it's characters are html-escaped, so now when I look at it's source code, it looks something like `&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;id_scriptscrap&quot;/&gt` where it should've been 
`<input type="text" id="id_scriptscrap"/>`.

Is there something I'm missing? Why would the first template output it without escaping, while the second does escape? Perhaps I did something wrong when creating the custom widget class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Perhaps I did something wrong when creating the custom widget class?

Probably, although it's impossible to tell since you don't post the code.

The reason why `form.as_p` works is that the `form._html_output()` method - which is what the various `as_foo` methods use - calls `mark_safe` on its output. However, each of the built-in widget classes *also* call `mark_safe` on their own output, which is why they work individually. You probably just need to do the same on your custom widget.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Just to clarify for future readers :) - the widget's render() method returned a string that wasn't marked with mark_safe() and thus the template escaped it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate cause: this also happens if you accidentally defined your form with widgets instead of fields (for example `password = forms.PasswordInput` instead of `password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)`